# Please explain what this Seq.map call will do in F#

Tags: f#

I encountered the following line in exercism.io solution for F#, but I have issues grasping with the Seq.map part will do. (Probably obvious, but number is an integer here)

```
let numberSequence = number |> string |> Seq.map (float >> (-) 48.0 >> (-) 0.0)
```

Can someone shed light on this for me?

Comment: In this case, Seq.map will convert the string version of the number into a sequence of chars. Each char will then have the math applied to it.

Comment: A clue that may be sufficient: string is a sequence of characters and can be as such the argument to `Seq.map`: `123 |> string |> Seq.map id` expression value is `seq ['1';'2';'3']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the function is something like:

```
let numberSequence number = number |> string |> Seq.map (float >> (-) 48.0 >> (-) 0.0)
```

then:

```
> numberSequence 654 ;;
val it : seq<float> = seq [6.0; 5.0; 4.0]
```

If so, what it does is:

`number |> string` Converts the number to a string

`string |> Seq.map` this could be tricky, a string implements IEnumerable, so it can be interpreted as a sequence of chars `seq<char>`. So here each char is "mapped" to a function.

Now let's have a look at the function, it turns out it's a composition of functions:

`float` converts the char to a float

`(-) 48.0` it's like `fun x -> 48. - x` so it subtract the previous result to 48

`(-) 0.0` Similarly subtract 0 to the previous result.

The function in the map part is trying to get the numerical value of the char. `Seq.map` applies that function to each element and construct a new sequence with each result.

As a side note, that function could have been easily written as:

```
let numberSequence number = number |> string |> Seq.map System.Char.GetNumericValue
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gustavo